# Express density as a ratio of height

Tags: ratio

D1 and D2 are densities

$$D1 = \frac{3*mass}{4*pi*r^3}  $$
$$D2 = \frac{3*mass}{pi(3rh^2-h^3)}  $$

and then $$\frac{D2}{D1} = \frac{3rh^2-h^3}{4r^3}$$

I'm not sure how to isolate the R and H so when given the two densities I can just calculate the ratio of $$\frac{H}{R}$$ Not given the mass, only the two densities are given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = \frac{h}{r}$. Then

$$\frac{D2}{D1} = \frac{3rh^2-h^3}{4r^3}\\
\frac{4D2}{D1} = 3(\frac{h}{r})^2-(\frac{h}{r})^3\\
\frac{4D2}{D1} = 3x^2-x^3\\
x^3 - 3x^2 + \frac{4D2}{D1} = 0$$

Unfortunately cubics aren't as easily solved as quadratics, though they do have exact formulas you can use. With the help of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%20-%203x%5E2%20%2B%204t%20%3D%200) you get the following:

Let $t = \frac{D2}{D1}$. Calculate

$$z = \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{t^2 - t} - 2 t + 1}$$

and then

$$\frac{h}{r} = z + \frac{1}{z} + 1$$